# How to delete an element every 8 elements in a list of strings on python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose that you have a list of strings like the following one:

```
the_list = ['02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)', '1.1%', '0.5%', '2.0%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)', '9.9%', '9.2%', '7.4%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (MoM)', '0.8%', '0.2%', '-0.2%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (YoY)', '10.0%', '9.3%', '6.0%', '',
            '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Index of Services', '1.0%', ' ', '1.2%', '']
```

Which every 8 elements appears `''`, which is an empty string, and it happens to be the same empty string that exists next to the one called   `GBP`

How could `the_list` variable be updated so that it deletes the `''` **element that appears every 8 elements** in the array of strings?

Comment: I just would like to know how can I delete the elements that are empty strings `''` except those that are next to the elements set as `   GBP` @OrkhanAliyev

Comment: One thing to note: it looks like you have gathered multiple rows of data into a single list. You should consider building this as a 2D list or a list of dictionaries or class objects to begin with which might make it easier to massage the format later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use list-comprehension to filter out the values at specific index:

```py
new_list = [word for idx, word in enumerate(the_list, 1) if idx % 8 != 0]
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```py
['02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Construction Output (MoM) (Jan)', '1.1%', '0.5%', '2.0%',
 '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'U.K. Construction Output (YoY) (Jan)', '9.9%', '9.2%', '7.4%',
 '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (MoM)', '0.8%', '0.2%', '-0.2%',
 '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'GDP (YoY)', '10.0%', '9.3%', '6.0%',
 '02:00', '  GBP', '', 'Index of Services', '1.0%', ' ', '1.2%']
```

Comment: Incredible, I didn't know list-comprehension at all, but thank you so much for your answer, it definitely solved mi issue. I would also check that topic out, seems interesting .

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
del the_list[::8]  # or del the_list[7::8] if you try to delete the 7th element of each line
```

Comment: That would not achieve what the OP asked.

Comment: @alexpdev actually, `del the_list[7::8] ` would work, but that's in a comment, but would be a decent answer to this question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Should the slice start at `2` instead of `7`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no, because you want the item at index `7` to be the first item deleted, then every 8 items after that

Comment: To be precise, it's the difference between "delete every 8th element starting with the first element" versus "delete every 8th element starting with the 8th element"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, ic...the OP wants to remove the last empty string in each "row", not the one starting at index 2 and repeating every 8.

Answer (score -1):

just use this code to find the element that you want to delete
in that case is empty string, in python is a false string so

```
for x in the_list:
    if not x:
        the_list.remove(x)
```

Comment: That would also remove those empty/false strings that are next to `  GBP` strings, which is not desired

Comment: just check the code, it would not remove that because this is part of the string

Comment: And in general, this is a bug-prone approach that is highly inefficient.

Comment: Trying to remove items while iterating this way will not give what you expect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating